# Javascript - How can I write my clean code?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I need to do a function on Jquery that write in a div some HTML elements.

Code is this :

```
function loadAppartamenti() {
    $('.profilo_2').empty();
    $('.profilo_2').html("<label class='article_span'>Inserisci Zona (es. Via/Località)</label> /
                          <input id='art_1' class='article_input' /> /
                          <label class='article_span'>Costo (€ Mese)</label> /
                          <input id='art_2' class='article_input' /> /
                          <label class='article_span'>Disponibilità (Periodo In Mesi)</label> /
                          <input id='art_3' class='article_input' /> /
                          <label class='article_span'>Condizioni</label> /
                          <input id='art_4' class='article_input' /> /
                          <label class='article_span'>Servizi Presenti</label> /
                          <input id='art_5' class='article_input' />");
}
```

I need to clean the code as clean as possible, so i've aligned it (I go to the new line when i write a line).

I know that on Javascript i can do it, adding a `/` at the end of each line. But maybe i wrong remember. In fact if i run this code on Chrome, the console says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

How can I fix this problem? I don't want to write the code on 1 line :)

Comment: What happens if you removed the extra '/'?  My guess would be that it should work.  It will only appear as 1 line in the rendered HTML, but that isn't where readability counts anyway (neither a user nor developer view).

Comment: by the way, this has nothing to do with jQuery, just JavaScript string syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a backslash at the end of each line rather than a forward slash:

```
var s = "one\
         two\
         three";
```

Comment: Daamn. Im about 30 minuts on this problem. My fault. Thanks hehe

Answer (score 4):

Have you thought about

```
var textArray = [...]; // insert your text content
var portfilo = $(".profilo_2");
for (var  i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    profilo.append(
        $("<label>").addClass("article_span").text(textArray[i])
    ).append(
        $("<input>").attr("id", "art_"+ i).addClass("input_span")
    )
}
```

You can cache / optimise it some more if you care.